# Issues with deleting arrays in session variable PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a bit of help with figuring out this loop in PHP. I am removing items from a shopping cart and the array data is stored inside of `$_session['products']`. The problem I have ran into is trying to get the cart to delete multiple items at once. This code functions just fine when removing one item at a time. With multiple items it will sometimes copy the item that wasn't deleted or delete everything but the items that were selected.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => Another Test
               [code] => 8456885345
               [qty] => 1
               [price] => 893.98 )
[1] => Array ( [name] => Another Test 2
               [code] => 11134455                  
               [qty] => 1
               [price] => 3.12 ) 
) 


if(isset($_GET["removemp"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
    {
        $product_code   = $_GET["removemp"];
        $return_url     = $_GET["return_url"];

        $product_explode = explode(',', $product_code);

        foreach($product_explode as $code)
        {
            foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
            {
                if($cart_itm["code"]!=$code){
                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                }

                $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate the array in order to delete the elements. Create a list of indices you ought to keep and copy only those to the update vector instead.

Comment: you want to delete? there is no `unset()` involved in your code

Comment: i suggest you use the product id as `key` of each main element inside your `$_SESSION['products']`. from there, you can delete how many you want based on user input, and of course use `unset()`

Comment: I'm new to working with these kind of variables. I normally stay to the realm of simple database interaction. The CODE field is actually the product id number. How would I go about using unset to remove the product? I tried using unset($_SESSION["products"][$code]) inside of the loop but nothing happened.

Comment: as long as you're pushing each batch of items using `$_SESSION['products'][$code] = $product` then you should be able to unset it using `unset($_SESSION["products"][$code])`

Answer (score 0):

Store the product ID's as the session cart array keys, and delete each item by storing the desired product ID's as a comma separated list (as your question above) in the `$_GET["removemp"]` param, eg:

```
    // where the array key is the product ID 

        Array ( 
            [12] => Array ( [name] => Another Test
                           [code] => 8456885345
                           [qty] => 1
                           [price] => 893.98 )
            [34] => Array ( [name] => Another Test 2
                           [code] => 11134455                  
                           [qty] => 1
                           [price] => 3.12 ) 
            ) 




            if(isset($_GET["removemp"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
                {
                    $product_code   = $_GET["removemp"];
                    $return_url     = $_GET["return_url"];

                    $product_explode = explode(',', $product_code);

                    foreach($product_explode as $code)
                    {

                     // and simply unset each cart array 

                      unset($_SESSION["products"][$code]);
                    }
                }
```

To set the array using the product ID as the array key:

```
$_SESSION["products"][$product_id] = array (   'name' => 'Another Test',
                                               'code' => 8456885345,
                                               'qty' => 1,
                                               'price' => 893.98 );
```

Comment: This may seem silly but how do I manually set the Array key value instead of it ordering them 0,1,2,3 etc.?

Comment: Just like so: `$_SESSION["products"][$product_id] = array (   'name' => 'Another Test',
              'code' => 8456885345,
              'qty' => 1,
              'price' => 893.98 );`

Comment: Instead of making the Product info the key I did the following to delete the item. Now it finds the main key and deletes the item.

foreach($product_explode as $code)
{
$key = key($_SESSION["products"]);
echo $key,"<br>";
  
unset($_SESSION["products"][$key]);
}